# revert to a previous commit in git locally, after a big merge

Tags: git, git-merge

Here is the case. I worked on my local branch simsim, tested and seemed good. Then I merged master in, which has hundreds of commits by co-workers. Two minutes later, I regret and want to revert back to my commit before the merge.

Sadly, I do not know the hash. And it is painful to fumble through half a thousand of commits to find it out.

It seems that the command
`$git reset --hard HEAD~2`
only brings me back two commits, in master though.

any quick way to revert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `git log simsim --not master` to locate the hash and then `revert` or `reset` back.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard @{1}
```

You can see the previous commits you were working on by running:

```
git reflog
```